# Badge for someone who has over 100 or 200 or whatever number of accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, badges

I think there should be a badge for those that have authored over a certain amount of accepted answers.

Comment: I like that idea - but do you mean the answerer of 100 accepted answers, or the question asker that accepted 100 answers?

Comment: @AviD I assume he means a person who has authored 100 accepted answers, which I agree is a commendable thing.

Comment: how about both?

Answer (score 2):

First off: yes, that is a nice idea and I like it. But also consider that as of now, +15 is given for each accepted answer.

This has also been [suggested on The Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1256#1256), with very little conclusive results. Although it does appear that badges are a constantly-changing thing, so I wouldn't say it'll never happen. We'll just have to wait and see...

[[AviD](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/459/avid)'s comment has also been discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41567/badge-for-accepting-answers)]

[for more exposure, consider posting this question on [The Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)]

Comment: While it would certainly garner more voting on Meta.SO, all site metas *are* monitored by SEI staff, so as far as thats concerned no need to post over there.

Comment: @AviD: more voting — and more discussion. A suggestion can be refined (e.g., what number of answers should trigger the badge?), for example.

Comment: With the logic of the answer there should be no badges for an answer that receives 10, 25 or whatever number of votes, as +10 is already received +10 for each vote.